# Incremental NET core upgrade for multiple sites that have the same code deployed running on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, ms-yarp

I have a scenario where we have multiple customers and each customer has one or more sites set up in IIS. Each site has the same code DLLs deployed and the difference between what they do is a mix of `web.config` and DB settings.

Current server setup:

[image: current server setup]

The codebase is currently on .NET 4.x and we're upgrading to .NET 6. Due to the size of the code, we're stuck with an incremental upgrade approach which requires YARP. Testing this locally works fine as we just set the yarp settings on the NET Core project to point to localhost:port. However, in production I can't find a way to do this for multiple sites.

Since locally, there is no DNS server, we cannot use urls and so we need to use localhost:port. but we don't want to have each customer to have an explicitly stated port for the old app as that won't scale when adding new customers.

Is there any way to group the sites together so that only .NET Framework site inside an IIS group can be called from the .NET Core site that is also within that same group?

Target server setup:

[image: target server setup]

Comment: "There is no DNS server"? But every machines has a `hosts` file.